# How to get all the parents of the treeitem?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I am programming in GWT

i have tree which is like

```
  1.A Folder
     1.Marketing Folder
     2.Sales Folder
        1.In Folder
           1.Invoice.txt
        2. Out Folder
  2.B folder
     1. xyz
        1.fgh 
     2. abc
  3.C foder
```

If i click on  Invoice.txt the output should be like

```
"A folder/Sales FOlder/In FOlder/Invoice.txt"
```

i am using  getParent method to display th output but it is show me only the

```
"In folder".
```

Plese some one help me to understand this,
How wil i get the complete path.

I am using tree Widget

Comment: I don't work with this, but it would seem like you just need to keep going all the way up. Consider using a StringBuilder and continually calling `getParent` on each node.

Comment: are you using a gwt Tree Widget, Celltree Widget or a simple HTML tree?

Comment: TreeItem? getParentItem() until you get null, concatenating each parent along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String getPath(TreeItem selectedItem) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    buildPath(selectedItem, builder);
    return builder.toString();
}

private void buildPath(TreeItem item, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (item.getParentItem() != null) {

        buildPath(item.getParentItem(), builder);  //build path

        builder.append('/');
    }
    builder.append(item.getText());
}
```

Comment: output of this code gives me null/null/null/null

 i put `builder.append(item.getText());` 
instead `builder.append(item.getUserObject());` for the correct output